# Why does this post appear as deleted from a user who is not its author?

Tags: support, review, flags, deleted-answers

On [fail to open system.install after transferring to debain](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/80510/fail-to-open-system-install-after-transferring-to-debain) there is a deleted answer. What I see about the user who deleted it is the following.

> [image: screenshot]

The user who deleted it is not the user who posted the answer. *Xio* is not one of the past names used from the user who answered.

The timeline for the answer is the following one.

> [image: screenshot]

Nothing is reported for the flag and the review histories. (It is not possible to select those entries from the moderator's menu, which normally means there is nothing to be shown for them.)

How can a user who has never been a moderator delete an answer written by another user?

I find strange the answer has been deleted in the same minute it was written. I would think it would not happen if the answer was added to a review queue; maybe it could happen if the answer was flagged and automatically deleted because that flag, but there are no  flags for that answer.

Comment: The *deleted by [user]* is a text that is generated when the post gets deleted. If the users changes their name later on, those generated texts are not re-rendered, hence the difference.In the timeline and usercard we always see the current name. Moderators do have access to the user displayname history.

Comment: Or was there a moderator with that name which isn't a moderator anymore?

Comment: @rene Xio is not one of the past names used from the user who answered. I am a moderator on _Drupal Answers_.

Comment: @PatrickHofman None of the moderators had that name. It seems also the account for _Xio_ was deleted, since in the second screenshot the username is not a link. (Compare _Xio_ with _ya.teck_ in that screenshot.)

Comment: @kiamlaluno any account merges?

Comment: @rene In that case, the name would appear as past name. At least that happened to me when another account was merged with mine.

Comment: OK, then this is a strange case. Needs a dev to sort out.

Comment: @rene Now that I look at my account, there isn't any _past name_ anymore, which happened in the past.

Comment: @rene is correct, that is a past name of that user as can be seen in comments on [this answer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/80662/27130).

Comment: @ShadowWizard In that case, I should see it listed as past name, but that account doesn't list any past name.

Comment: Also, a past name should be replaced in every place a username is listed. I should not see two usernames that refer to the same account, in the timeline of a post.

Comment: Yeah, the account merge explains it all.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The user had an account merge shortly after that deletion (probably an unregistered user, but I don't feel like looking into it further from mobile). That user's name was Xio and the user had deleted the answer (as its author) prior to being deleted due to the merge. The merge process itself does not transfer past delete vote information over to the new profile - that's just more stuff to do in an already fairly complicated merge process.